# jQuery: появление картинки у элемента

Tags: jquery

Помогите пожалуйста сделать так чтобы не у всех элементов .qwe изменялись стили, а только у того элемента, который стоит в блоке  .commentBlock.

```
$(document).ready(function(){

$('.commentBlock').mouseover(function(){
    $('.qwe').css('width','13px');
    $('.qwe').css('height','13px');
    $('.qwe').css('background-image','url("tt.png")');
    $('.qwe').css('background-position','-20px -4px');

}).mouseout(function(){
    $('.qwe').css('width','13px');
    $('.qwe').css('height','13px');
    $('.qwe').css('background-image','');
    $('.qwe').css('background-position','');
});
});
```

Comment: И на будущее:

    $('.qwe').css('width','13px');
    $('.qwe').css('height','13px');

Можно записывать так:

    $('.qwe').css({'width':'13px','height':'13px'});

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Используйте поиск дочернего класса.
Через `children()` или `find()`.

Answer (score 1):

Ну во-первых чтоб не играться с потомками и их родителями советую использовать mouseenter() вместо mouseover() и mouseleave() вместо mouseout() соответственно, кстати такой же совет дается в доках jquery.
А по поводу изменения конкретного экземпляра класса, то используй конструкцию вида $(this.children[x]), где X-ом будет порядковый номер экземпляра класса #commentBlock, т.е. его потомок, таким образом ты можешь перемещаться по своему DOM-дереву

```
 $('#commentBlock').mouseenter(function(){
            $(this.children[0]).css(что тебе надо);
            });
  });
 $('#commentBlock').mouseleave(function(){
            $(this.children[0]).css(что тебе надо);
            });
 })
```

Comment: Может вопрос не так поставил. Мне необходимо чтобы при наведении на блок .commentBlock изменялся css стиль .qwe, но не у всех, а только который находится в блоке commentBlock
  
        <div id='commentBlock'>
 <div class='qwe'>-</div>
 </div>

Comment: <div id='commentBlock'> в jquery выглядит как $('#commentBlock')

 $('#commentBlock').mouseenter(function(){
//следующая строка и есть твой .qwe, который находится только в //commentBlock 
            $(this.parentNode.children[0]).css(что тебе надо);
            });
  });

что касаемо описания css-стилей, то сходи сюда http://jquery.page2page.ru/index.php5/%D0%A0%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B0_%D1%81_CSS

Answer (score 1):

Таки вот так `$('#commentBlock .qwe')`, или как вам написали выше `$('#commentBlock').children('.qwe')`. Или вы так попробовали, да не получилось?

Comment: Пишу вот так:
$(document).ready(function(){

$('#commentBlock').mouseenter(function(){
   $(this.children[0]).css('background-image', 'url("tt.png")');
            });
 
 $('#commentBlock').mouseleave(function(){
   $(this.children[0]).css('background-image', '');
            });

});

Стиль элемента меняется, но только первого элемента, как исправить? Помогите пожалуйста

Comment: $(document).ready(function(){
   $('#commentBlock .qwe').mouseenter(function(){              $(this).css('background-image', 'url("tt.png")'); });
$('#commentBlock .qwe').mouseleave(function(){ $(this).css('background-image', ''); });
});​

Вам написали, как сделать, вы сделали по-своему и говорите, что не получилось:). 
Вот specially for you http://jsfiddle.net/FsrYn/ , только здесь просто с цветами, а не с фоновой картинкой.

Comment: В том то и все дело что мне нужно чтобы не при наводе на блок qwe окрашивался он сам, а при наводе на блок commentBlock, перейдите и посмотрите, думаю поймете что я имею ввиду http://jsfiddle.net/FsrYn/1/

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/FsrYn/2/ Ну так что ли?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/FsrYn/3/ могу еще предложить вот так:). 
А вообще, учитесь задавать вопросы максимально конкретно. Экономит время для всех.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/FsrYn/4/ . Вообще, не должно быть двух и более элементов на странице с одинаковыми id , вот и не работает. А вообще, идите-ка читайте теорию по css и jquery. А то всем нужно обязательно что-то сделать, но при этом почему-то считается, что знание основ совсем необязательно.
P.S. Похоже, после этого комментария я не смогу больше их добавлять.

Answer (score 1):

Почему не написать просто через ф-цию $().hover()? или это deprecated?
Я бы рекомендовал не лезть js-ом напрямую в стили, а работать с CSS-классами

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
    $('#commentBlock').mouseenter(function(){
        $(this).find('.qwe').addСlass('qwe-hover');
    });
    $('#commentBlock').mouseleave(function(){
        $(this).find('.qwe').removeClass('qwe-hover');
    });
 });
```

Работает в разы быстрее, особенно если нужно изменять не одно свойство

Comment: А можно, плиз, какой-нибудь прув, что работа с классом будет "в разы быстрее", чем работа со стилем для случая, когда стиль нужно изменить только один?

Comment: Не знаю что такое "прув" :D это имперические данные, полученные путем наступления не на одни грабли) 
Как показывает практика, одно свойство можно поменять если оно не затрагивает размеров или положения/позиционирования элементов, например цвет текста или изменение background-position, в остальных случаях рекомендуют работать с классами.